# Yoga 260 on Xubuntu 22.04 - Wifi not working at all

Tags: networking, wireless, lenovo

I have a Lenovo Yoga 260 here and have problems to get Wifi working. Its exactly this model:

```
$ sudo lshw
yoga                        
    Beschreibung: Notebook
    Produkt: 20FES3TE00 (LENOVO_MT_20FE_BU_Think_FM_ThinkPad Yoga 260)
    Hersteller: LENOVO
    Version: ThinkPad Yoga 260
    Seriennummer: MP177CUL
    Breite: 64 bits
    Fähigkeiten: smbios-2.8 dmi-2.8 smp vsyscall32
    Konfiguration: administrator_password=disabled chassis=notebook family=ThinkPad Yoga 260 power-on_password=disabled sku=LENOVO_MT_20FE_BU_Think_FM_ThinkPad Yoga 260 uuid=bd113a4c-21ee-11b2-a85c-c147ded6772c
```

I tried to look for the network controllers, but it looks like there is no wifi at all?

```
$ sudo lshw -c network
  *-network                 
       Beschreibung: Ethernet interface
       Produkt: Ethernet Connection I219-LM
       Hersteller: Intel Corporation
       Physische ID: 1f.6
       Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       Logischer Name: enp0s31f6
       Version: 21
       Seriennummer: fc:45:96:66:cf:a4
       Kapazität: 1Gbit/s
       Breite: 32 bits
       Takt: 33MHz
       Fähigkeiten: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       Konfiguration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.15.0-79-generic firmware=0.13-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       Ressourcen: irq:125 memory:f1200000-f121ffff
  *-network
       Beschreibung: Ethernet interface
       Physische ID: c
       Bus-Informationen: usb@1:1
       Logischer Name: usb0
       Seriennummer: 8a:49:0c:5b:17:da
       Fähigkeiten: ethernet physical
       Konfiguration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=5.15.0-79-generic duplex=half firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.111.43 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair
```

Sorry, that the output is in german.. However, the second network controller is my phone connected via USB tethering. But the first controller sounds like a typical ethernet controller, but the yoga physically does not have an ethernet plug?!

Also `lspci | grep Network` does not return anything

Output of the askubuntu wireless detection script: https://justpaste.it/6llpp

And

```
$ ifconfig -a
enp0s31f6: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether fc:45:96:66:cf:a4  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  memory 0xf1200000-f1220000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Lokale Schleife)
        RX packets 10417  bytes 825839 (825.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 10417  bytes 825839 (825.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

usb0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.111.179  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.111.255
        inet6 fe80::f686:9ef1:6371:9e2b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b2:ab:0d:9f:dd:cd  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 4317  bytes 4016788 (4.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2602  bytes 506687 (506.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Output of wireless script:

```
########## wireless info START ##########
Report from: 17 Aug 2023 09:32 CEST +0200
Booted last: 17 Aug 2023 00:00 CEST +0200
Script from: 25 Jan 2020 03:34 UTC +0000
##### release ###########################
Distributor ID:    Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:    jammy
##### kernel ############################
Linux 5.15.0-79-generic #86-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jul 10 16:07:21 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7
##### desktop ###########################
Xubuntu
##### lspci #############################
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I219-LM [8086:156f] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Ethernet Connection I219-LM [17aa:2233]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
##### lsusb #############################
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 18d1:4ee3 Google Inc. Nexus/Pixel Device (tether)
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 138a:0090 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS7500 Touch Fingerprint Sensor
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 13d3:5248 IMC Networks Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 056a:5090 Wacom Co., Ltd Pen and multitouch sensor
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
##### PCMCIA card info ##################
##### rfkill ############################
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
##### secure boot #######################
'mokutil' is not installed (package "mokutil").
##### lsmod #############################
wmi_bmof               16384  0
wmi                    32768  2 wmi_bmof,think_lmi
##### interfaces ########################
##### ifconfig ##########################
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s31f6: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enp0s31f6' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
6: usb0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'usb0' [IF2]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 192.168.111.179/24 brd 192.168.111.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute usb0
       valid_lft 3483sec preferred_lft 3483sec
    inet6 fe80::f686:9ef1:6371:9e2b/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
##### iwconfig ##########################
lo        no wireless extensions.
enp0s31f6  no wireless extensions.
usb0      no wireless extensions.
##### route #############################
default via 192.168.111.160 dev usb0 proto dhcp metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev usb0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.111.0/24 dev usb0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.111.179 metric 100 
##### resolv.conf #######################
[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search .
##### network managers ##################
Installed:
    NetworkManager
Running:
root         748       1  0 Aug15 ?        00:00:04 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
##### NetworkManager info ###############
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         usb0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/6
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Google Inc.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Nexus/Pixel Device (tether)
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rndis_host
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 5.15.0-79-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               RNDIS device
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'usb0' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               4 (full)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               4 (full)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/net/usb0
GENERAL.PATH:                           pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1:1.0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       usb0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Kabelgebundene Verbindung 2
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       9bd3c4c1-439e-3253-82d6-b618bebecd1e
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/4
GENERAL.METERED:                        yes (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.PROMISC:                no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.111.179/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.111.160
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 192.168.111.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.111.160, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.111.160
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        broadcast_address = 192.168.111.255
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        dhcp_lease_time = 3600
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.111.160
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.111.160
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        expiry = 1692261014
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        host_name = yoga
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        ip_address = 192.168.111.179
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        next_server = 192.168.111.160
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_nis_domain = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_nis_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_root_path = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       routers = 192.168.111.160
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::f686:9ef1:6371:9e2b/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 1024
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/5
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   9bd3c4c1-439e-3253-82d6-b618bebecd1e | Kabelgebundene Verbindung 2
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp0s31f6
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Intel Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Ethernet Connection I219-LM
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         e1000e
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 5.15.0-79-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               0.13-4
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp0s31f6' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.6/net/enp0s31f6
GENERAL.PATH:                           pci-0000:00:1f.6
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.PROMISC:                no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: --
##### NetworkManager.state ##############
[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
##### NetworkManager config #############
[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3
[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved
[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma
[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-31-mac-addr-change]
match-device=driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
##### NetworkManager profiles ###########
##### Netplan config ####################
[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
##### iw reg get ########################
Region: Europe/Berlin (based on set time zone)
global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (755 - 928 @ 2), (N/A, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)
##### iwlist channels ###################
lo        no frequency information.
enp0s31f6  no frequency information.
usb0      no frequency information.
##### iwlist scan #######################
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.
enp0s31f6  Interface doesn't support scanning.
usb0      Interface doesn't support scanning.
##### module infos ######################
##### module parameters #################
##### /etc/modules ######################
##### modprobe options ##################
[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode
[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci
[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac
[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off
[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode
[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
##### rc.local ##########################
grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory
##### pm-utils ##########################
##### udev rules ########################
##### dmesg #############################
[12480.290761] rndis_host 1-1:1.0 usb0: unregister 'rndis_host' usb-0000:00:14.0-1, RNDIS device
[127859.375338] rndis_host 2-1:1.0 usb0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:00:14.0-1, RNDIS device, <MAC address>
[127917.111312] rndis_host 2-1:1.0 usb0: unregister 'rndis_host' usb-0000:00:14.0-1, RNDIS device
[127917.467181] rndis_host 2-1:1.0 usb0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:00:14.0-1, RNDIS device, <MAC address>
[127918.371410] rndis_host 2-1:1.0 usb0: unregister 'rndis_host' usb-0000:00:14.0-1, RNDIS device
[127918.716819] rndis_host 2-1:1.0 usb0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:00:14.0-1, RNDIS device, <MAC 'usb0' [IF2]>
########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: What about `lsusb`?

Comment: Is WLAN disabled in BIOS settings?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: Try `(export LANG="C";sudo lshw --class network)` to get messages in English and more information.

Comment: I used the script (cool), lsusb output is in there too: https://justpaste.it/6llpp

Comment: Your paste service is broken, so add the output into your question (formatted).

Comment: its has been added by @mpboden

Answer (score 3):

[This page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Laptop/Lenovo#Yoga_Series) claimed in 2018 that wireless is working.

So your device has either a [hardware switch](https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/fixed-lenovo-laptop-not-detecting-wireless-network/#F2) that turns off wifi completely or no wireless module is present (since wifi is physically not found).

Lenovo provides a [handbook](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/yoga260_ug_de.pdf)  to download. (German Version - obviously needed)

Execution of `ip a` should list all of your network devices. A wireless adapter should look like this:

```
4: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether xxxx  brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet x.y.z/24 brd x.y.z.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp3s0
   valid_lft 842064sec preferred_lft 842064sec
inet6 ffff::ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff/64 scope link noprefixroute 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

If you do not have a HW switch, either your UEFI is masking the device completely or the wireless hardware is not built in (the Yoga handbook should tell you where to look)

Comment: did not find a hardware switch in the manual nor on the notebook. So but to make sure, the data I posted definitely says there is no wifi card available?

Comment: see my updated answer. (On a Lenovo Thinkpad P14s) Your `lshw` clearly indicates, that no hardware was found. That is more than just not having a driver.

Answer (score 0):

the idea of switching to a more recent kernel could readjust the latest drivers for your computer

Ahead of the formal Ubuntu 22.04.3 point release due next week (August 10) Canonical has issued an updated kernel to existing LTS existing users to install. It back-ports the Linux 6.2 kernel used in Ubuntu 23.04 “Lunar Lobster”.

Typically, HWE updates roll out once the formal point release itself is made. This time the update has arrived earlier – which is great news for those on the LTS as it means they can benefit from all the new features in Linux 6.2 without having to wait for ISOs (they don’t need) to be released.

To install the new kernel on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS just pop open the Software Updater tool, run a check for updates, and install those listed. When you reboot (if you have more than one kernel installed) be sure to select the 6.2 version.

You can also update via the command line by running:

> sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade or sudo apt dist-upgrade.

Comment: based on the date in the answer this looks like an outdated copy/paste? But in context of the problem here, you just think it _might_ help to update the kernel?

Comment: Based on OP's original information, I am going to say that I think OP is missing a wifi card in their system, because there's no network interfaces that seem to be listed except Ethernet and an external USB device.  It detects an 'ethernet' device not a wifi device, which could be a device misrepresentation but updating to get 'driver' changes or Kernel updates doesn't change the underlying device not being detected proper as a wifi card.